# Conditional filtering based off the passed parameters

Tags: mysql, sql, pymysql

I have a table Users :

```
FirstName, LastName, Status, City
```

And more fields. I display this table on the front end and I need to filter based off each column, 
on the server side.
Currently the SQL Query fetches all the data:

```
SELECT * FROM Users
```

But I use graphql, and I want to be able to pass only the selected filter to the query,
And example have :

```
WHERE Status = 'single'
```

I use `python ( pymysql)` on the **backend**.
How would I do that so that example after status is selected single, when he starts to query by name
it queries the ones whose status is single, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I get exactly what you want, but it sounds to me you need to apply filter over filters. That is, with a first filter you reduce the number of rows, and then you want to apply a second filter to further reduce the number of rows, and so on.

If this is the case you'll need to keep the filtering conditions in the user session (probably using a list, array, or set), in order to accumulate them all.

The first time, the list won't have any element so your table will show all the rows and your SQL will look like:

```
select * from users
```

When the user adds a selection filter (status 'single') the interface will add it to the list. Using the list your backend will produce the new SQL:

```
select * from users
  where status = 'single'
```

Next, when the user adds a new selection filter (city 'Rome') you add it to the list. Using the list the backend will produce the new SQL:

```
select * from users
  where status = 'single'
    and city = 'Rome'
```

And so on. So you need to take care of two things:

- Maintaining the "Filter List": adding/removing/clearing filter criteria when the user clicks on different places/buttons on the interface.
- Dynamically build your SQL using the elements on the list.

That's it!

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this by simply using parameters in your query. You should do that anyway to prevent SQL injection attacks. Your query would look like:

```
Select * from users
where 
 (@Firstname is null or FirstName = @FirstName) and 
 (@LastName is null or LastName = @LastName) and 
 (@Status is null or Status = @Status) and
 (@City is null or City = @City)
```

So that your query string is always constant, you only change the parameters. Check the documentation of your driver how to add the parameters and values. Most language drivers support named parameters but I don't have an idea about how pymysql driver does it.